# How do I find the centre of a mesh?

Tags: c#, xna, mesh

Is a way to find where the centre of the car is? I have to manually move the wheel to the centre of the car, rotate it and translate it back.

```
tireMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(2.6f, -4.5f, 1.75f) *
                             Matrix.CreateRotationX(pitch) *
                             Matrix.CreateRotationZ(roll) *
                             Matrix.CreateTranslation(-2.7f, -4.7f, -1.75f);
```

Moving it manually does work but I cant find the exact centre of the car, there must be a better way of doing this. All the car parts are in the same FBX file

Comment: I don't know about "exact" but you could put a bounding box around the car and find the center of the rectangle

Answer (score 0):

I think it works, but I didn't test it.

```
matrix.X = box.Min.X+(box.Max.X-box.Min.X)/2;
matrix.Y = box.Min.Y+(box.Max.Y-box.Min.Y)/2;
matrix.Z = box.Min.Z+(box.Max.Z-box.Min.Z)/2;
```

To create the `BoundingBox box`, you can use [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2438/how-do-i-create-bounding-boxes-with-xna-4-0)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind figured it out. I had to use ModelBone to store the wheels as bones of the car, store the initial transforms of the wheels and I can just perform rotations on the wheels without having to translate them anywhere. 
For future references or if anyone else who might want to do similar thing, here is the code

```
    Model carModel;
        Matrix carWorldMatrix;

        ModelBone fr_wheel;
        ModelBone fl_wheel;
        ModelBone bl_wheel;
        ModelBone br_wheel;
        //Matrices for storing the initial transform of each wheel 
        Matrix fr_transform;
        Matrix fl_transform;
        Matrix br_transform;
        Matrix bl_transform;

        Matrix[] transforms;

        float wheelRotation;
        float wheelSteerAngle;
        float carRotation;

public void Load(ContentManager content)
{
      carModel = content.Load<Model>("car");

      fr_wheel = carModel.Bones["fr_tire"];
      fl_wheel = carModel.Bones["fl_tire"];
      bl_wheel = carModel.Bones["bl_tire"];
      br_wheel = carModel.Bones["br_tire"];

      fr_transform = fr_wheel.Transform;
      fl_transform = fl_wheel.Transform;
      br_transform = br_wheel.Transform;
      bl_transform = bl_wheel.Transform;

      transforms = new Matrix[carModel.Bones.Count];
}

public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
     carModel.Root.Transform = carWorldMatrix;

     Matrix tireRotation = Matrix.CreateRotationX(wheelRotation) *
                           Matrix.CreateRotationY(wheelSteerAngle);

     fr_wheel.Transform = tireRotation * fr_transform;//this will apply the rotation to the     front right wheel

}

public void Draw(ref Camera camera)
{
     carModel.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);

     foreach (ModelMesh mesh in carModel.Meshes)
     {
         foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
         {
             effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
             effect.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index];
             effect.View = camera.viewMatrix;
             effect.Projection = camera.projectionMatrix;
         }
         mesh.Draw()
     }
}
```